# Is there an algorithm for iterating around an ArrayList in a circle?

Tags: java, list, iterator

That is, at the moment when I reached the end of the sheet so that the next element is zero.

Comment: Please, add more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sheet? What zero? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

Consider the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   // Output will be: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7;0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7;...
   System.out.println(i % 8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(); // + add some values to the list

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    someMethod();
    if (some condition) {
        break; // you need to add some break condition, otherwise, this will be an infinite loop
    }
    if (i == list.size() - 1) {
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you've declared and populated an `ArrayList` which I'll call `list`, then you simply iterate modulo the list size.  Exactly how to write this depends on what you want to do.

1) Keep on going forever, circularly:

```
int index = 0;
while (true) {
    value = list.get(index);
    … process value here …
    index = (index + 1) % list.size();
    // or equivalently to previous line: if (++index >= list.size) index = 0;
}
```

2)  Loop through the list exactly once but starting at some arbitrary point `base`:

```
for (int offset = 0; offset < list.size(); offset++) {
    int index = (base + offset) % list.size();
    value = list.get(index);
    … process value here …
}
```

and so forth...

Ways can be designed to use an explicit iterator rather than indexing, but it all depends what you want to achieve.